# Проблема с конфигурацией в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, config, configuration

Начал изучать Symfony столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
В официальной документации сказано, что можно свои "параметры" в config/services.yaml описывать, и потом где-то использовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня совершенно чистый Symfony без каких-либо изменений, пытаюсь повторить тоже самое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получаю ошибку тупо на объявлении этого "параметра", без какого-либо его использования где-то еще

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильная структура **yaml** файла, сделайте отступ через **tab** для значения **app.admin_email**, чтобы получилось следующим образом:

```
parameters:
    app.admin_email: "something@example.com"
```